# Test Radio Button Text Equality in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to test if my radio button text is equal to "PayPal". The alert box displays "PayPal", but the equality test that would show or hide DIV content failed.

```
 <%= radio_button_tag "order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]", 
 method.id, method == @order.available_payment_methods.first, data: 
 {behavior: "toggle-products"} %>



 <div id="confirmpaypal" class="pull-right">
  <%= button_tag "Continue" , type: 'submit', 
    class: 'btn btn-primary btn-small' do %>
    "Confirm"  
  <% end %>
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"][data-behavior="toggle-products"]').click(function(evt) {
        alert($(this).closest('label').text());
        if($(this).closest('label').text() == "PayPal") {
            $('#confirmpaypal').show();
        } else {
            $('#confirmpaypal').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Put a console.log or alert inside the `if` to see if it gets fired. Maybe it is entering the `if` but your `show()` and `hide()` are not working

Comment: As per sample code above alert box displays "PayPal", but the  "if == 'PayPal'" failed.

Comment: Yeah move the alert inside the `if` statement to see if that block is even firing

Comment: It does not fire inside the if statement.

Comment: Are you sure your label does not have any unintended white space? You can add $(this).closest('label').text().trim() to the if block to test.

Comment: Jon, it worked. Many thanks!